# Can BR replace JSR to a certain extent?(LC-3)

Tags: lc3

I think that if I put the address of the instruction following BR into R7 and then jump to the address of of the subroutine.Is it just JSR to some extent?I'd like to ask what's the difference between BR and JSR that makes them distinct.

Comment: Is there a way to store PC + 1 in R7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to ask what's the difference between BR and JSR that makes them distinct.

JSR sets R7 to point to the instruction after JSR. That is what makes BR different from JSR.

(There is another minor difference. JSR has a much longer range, because it uses an 11 bit offset instead of a 9 bit offset, which lets it reach labels that are 4 times further.)

> Can BR replace JSR to a certain extent?

Yes. If you couldn't use JSR for some reason, you could work around it by using BR instead.

Here's how you could call a subroutine using JSR:

```
main         JSR subroutine
             ; back from subroutine

subroutine   ; do something
             ; ...
             RET
```

Here's the equivalent code using BR/LEA:

```
main         LEA R7, return
             BR subroutine
return       ; back from subroutine

subroutine   ; do something
             ; ...
             RET
```

(Note: this is not precisely equivalent, because LEA sets the CC register, and JSR does not.)

Answer (score 0):

Well you are quite true that they are the same on context, but their instant numbers are having a slight difference.

- BR calculates PC Offset 7, which means your branched new instruction should be in between -128 to 127 off the current PC + 1.
- JSR calculates PC Offset 9, which means your jumped new instruction should be between -512 to 511, which is a much wider range compared to BR.

LC-3 due have identical instructions though, namely JSRR and JMP, they are just the same instruction (and I personally think which is not a perfect design, since they can just change one into another more usable opcode such as left shift or right shift of digits, wo make multiplication and division much quicker and easier).